# My logo doesn't scale until a certain browser size, creating overlapping errors

Tags: css, scale, overlap

Site can be seen here:

http://www.harringtonsproperty.co.uk/property-sales/

When reducing the size of the browser, the logo at the top left overlaps the advanced search area below. How can I stop this happening? Please bear in mind I have relatively basic CSS skills!

Thanks!

Comment: please add your code. It will make this post a better reference in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 

/* Adjust the max-width to be the measure at which
 you want your logo to start changing and then 
add the responsive CSS for the logo here */


    }
```

**Note:** Don't forget to strip off the responsive CSS for the logo from the old location to avoid conflict.